# Bash - Filter out directories from ls -la output, but leave directory "."

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to count size of all files and subdirectories starting from `./` using oneliner:

```
ls -laR | grep -v "\.\." | awk '{total += $5} END {print total}'
```

but this counts size of subdirectories twice because output of `ls -laR | grep -v "\.\."` is:

```
.:
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 29 22:59 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   55 Nov 29 02:19 131
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Nov 29 01:28 abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1000 Nov 29 01:27 access.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 29 22:24 asd
-rwx------ 1 root root  458 Nov 29 02:54 oneliners.sh
-rwx------ 1 root root 2136 Nov 29 17:56 regexp.sh.skript

./asd:
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 29 22:24 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21298 Nov 29 22:26 asd
```

so it counts directory asd twice. once in listing of directory `.:` as:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 29 22:24 asd
```

and 2nd time in listing of directory `./asd:` as:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 29 22:24 .
```

I expect, this will happen for every subdirectory. Is there a way to remove them once from `ls` output? Usint `grep -v '^d'` removes all directories, so they wont be counted at all. I know I can do it simply bu using `du -sb`, but I need it to be done with fancy oneliner.

Comment: huh? what's wrong with `du`?

Comment: Do NOT parse the output of ls.™

Comment: _but I need it to be done with fancy oneliner_ . Isn't `du -sh` oneliner?

Comment: yeah, but if I use `du -sh`, there wont be anything more to do, so it wont be fancy.

Comment: You're not looking for a fancy oneliner, but a stupid one that might impress noobs but is bound to break. By the way, if you really want to, at least use a sensible tool like `find`.

Comment: In that case, you are on your own. No one here at SO will give you a highfalutin code. Good luck.

Comment: well ok, thanks for info and sorry for asking stupid question.

Comment: If you insist, just divide by the link count. `$5/$2` instead of `$5`. It will also "fix" the situation where you have files with multiple hard links (all of which should reside below the cwd...) Fyi `du` already takes hard links into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -FlaR |grep -v '\s\.\{1,\}/$' |awk '{total += $5} END {print total}'
```

includes the size of folders inside '.', but not the size of '.' itself. Comparing with du, the answer is quite different -as du is about the space on disk (relates to blocks).
The answer I get using your awk script is closer to what the OS reports -if you subtract the directory sizes you get a match, which suggests that MacOS X uses a method similar to

```
ls -FlaR |grep -v '^d.*/$' |awk '{total += $5} END {print total}'
```

for calculating the size of the content of a folder.

Comment: Thanks for help. It was homework to do oneliner to count space like `du -sb .` does, but to do it in a fancy way.
after reading through all stuff came up with this:
`find -ls | tr -s " " | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | cut -d " " -f 7 | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'`